# Is possible to create a new cart for a customer after he has done an order?

Tags: checkout, cart, magento2.2, rest-api

On my frontend, using the Magento 2.2 REST API, I have the following situation: a customer has the possibility to order products and specify the delivery date **for each product**.

For example: I can order **Item A** and want it to be shipped **tomorrow** and then order **Item B** and want it to be shipped **next week**.

To achive this, I store products on te frontend during the shopping and, when it's time for the checkout, I do the following:

1. Add **Item A** to cart
2. Do checkout (specifing delivery date in shipping information)
3. Add **Item B** to cart
4. Do checkout (specifing delivery date in shipping information)

The issue I'm running into: at the end of **point 2** (when the first checkout is done) if I try to retreive customer's cart I get a **404 - No entity with customerId = [customer id]**. It seems like the customer is deleted or something like that. Or maybe the cart is no more valid? Trying to create a new one I get a **Deconding error.** as response.

What I'm asking: is it possible to do what I described? If true, how can I do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I had a bug on my request. If someone needs this because like me you are at the beginning with Magento, here's how to achieve this one:

1. After the first checkout proceed with creating a new quote for the customer: `POST http://<host>/rest/default/V1/carts/mine`
2. Retrieve the new cart: `GET http://<host>/rest/default/V1/carts/mine`

Remember to pass **customer's token** in request's headers if using this API path (`/mine`):

`Authorization: Bearer [CUSTOMER_TOKEN]`

That's it!